# Bit vector comparison in Chisel

Tags: arrays, scala, vector, hdl, chisel

I have a vector of 4 bits, where I want to check if a single bit from the vector from the vector is a 1. So, basically I want to have loop with 4 iterations, where the first iteration will check if the first bit from the vector is a 1, and then in the next iteration check if the second bit is a 1 and so on.

I have tried with a switch statement shown below, but it doesn't work like I want it to.

```
  for(i <- 0 until ways) { //ways = 3
      switch(current_way(i)){
         is(UInt(1)){
         way_dout(i) := way.io.dout((i+1)*line_size-1,i*line_size)
      }
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, to help us give you the best answers, you should show us your instantiations of your variables (i.e., what type is current_way, way_dout, and ways?).

---

There are a number of approaches here. One idea is this:

```
val ways_vector = Wire(Vec(num_ways, Bool())
val way_dout = Wire(init=Vec.fill(num_ways){UInt(0, width = line_size)})
... 
// set values of ways_vector...
...
for (i <- 0 until num_ways) {
  when (ways_vector(i)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But `for` loops are ugly. Maps show your intent more clearly:

```
val way_dout = 
  ways_vector.zipWithIndex.map{ case (w, i) => 
    Mux(w, 
      way.io.dout((i+1)*line_size-1, i*line_size),
      UInt(0))}
```

`zipWithIndex` is a scala-ism, and it brings a lot of awesome power to hardware design.

Answer (score 0):

So you want way_dout(i) to have the value from the selected bit from way.io.dout when current_way(i) is set and zero otherwise, right? You can do something like this:

```
for(i <- 0 until ways) { //ways = 3
    way_dout(i) := current_way(i) & way.io.dout((i+1)*line_size-1,i*line_size)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I doesn't seem to work your way either. So, current_way is a 4-bit vector, and for each iteration I want to check each bit at a time starting from LSB. If the bit is 1, then I want way_dout(i) to get the data from way.io.dout(...), otherwise I want way_dout(i) to store zeros.

Comment: @user2466860 I didn't test the code, but it's gotta do what u just said. Do u get any errors at compile/elaboration? Could u describe why it doesn't work?